# Between and Join in single query

Tags: sql

```
gradeid | startrange | endrange
----------------------
A    | 50000  | 1000000
B    | 25000  | 49999
C    | 10000  | 24999

Employee 
id | salary
-----------
1  | 23000
2  | 20000
3  | 100000
```

I want to get all employee for a grade in single query. as there are no common fields, I can do this with two sub queries.

```
 select id from employee where salary 
    between (select startrange from grade where gradeid='A')
 and (select endrange from grade where gradeid='A')
```

Any other better SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE #grades(gradeid VARCHAR(100), startrange INT, endrange INT);

INSERT INTO #grades 
VALUES ('A', 50000, 1000000),('B', 25000, 49999),('C', 10000, 24999);

CREATE TABLE #Employee(id  INT, salary INT);

INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES(1, 23000),(2, 20000),(3, 100000);

SELECT e.*
FROM #Employee e
JOIN #grades g
  ON e.salary BETWEEN startrange AND endrange
WHERE g.gradeid = 'A';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387077)**</kbd>

Comment: That was perfect SQL Query !

Comment: @lad2025 but the performance wont be good as compare to subquery approach

Comment: @PreetamPurbia Do you compare execution plans? Grades table is simple lookup table, does it have any indexes?